# Relation ship between Track width, Impedance, Dielectric and copper thickness

Tags: pcb, impedance, trace, copper, dielectric

I like to know the relationship between different factors like track width, impedance, dielectric and copper thickness.

After quite a reading I got to know that as the track width of a cline is decreased, there is a decrease in the impedance, Trace width is indirectly proportional to impedance. For every 0.025mm change of track width, there is a 5-6 ohm change in impedance.

I want to derive the relationship like above between the other.

Comment: To 'derive' some data points from which you can infer a relationship, you need either some pretty hairy integration (my maths PhD boss took 3 weeks to get his head round some of the analytic techniques involved) or you do a finite element computation (which is what I did in those 3 weeks). Much joy, we got the same answer. A rule of thumb for today - 50 ohms impedance microstrip has a w/h ratio of 2 on FR4.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple formula, and no simple proportionality between the trace geometry and the characteristic impedance. There are approximate formulas, like these from [Microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/microstrip)

[image]

where

[image]

or, from [Chemandy.com](https://chemandy.com/calculators/microstrip-transmission-line-calculator.htm),

[image]

These are empirical formulas, developed by measuring designs with different parameters, and finding a formula to fit the observed data. There is some limited range of \$W/H\$ and \$\varepsilon_R\$ over which they are valid, which you should check before using the formulas. As you can see, they are also fairly complicated to calculate, not just a few steps on your pocket calculator.

These formulas were widely used in past times, when running an FEM analysis to estimate the impedance was a time-consuming task. Nowadays we can do that in a few seconds, and there's no real need to rely on these fitting formulas.

Comment: TL;DR Or you could use one of the many online calculators such as https://cecas.clemson.edu/cvel/emc/calculators/PCB-TL_Calculator/index.html to generate numerical results.